# Should I insert ACL tables into my database or create a separate Database?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, spring-security, acl

I'm working on a JEE application of managing Users and I want to secure it using Spring Security ACL , I have my database which contains all the tables (User,Roles..) and I have a script of ACL Tables (acl_sid,acl_class...) Should I insert ACL tables into my database or create a separate Database ?

Comment: Please I need some help in this, it's really urgent .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A MySQL "database" is really just a "schema", as defined by every other database vendor
2. You can easily communicate between schemas by using the fully qualified name (schemaName.tableName)
3. It won't make a huge difference other than making your main schema a little less cluttered.